# Why are these mesh objects visible in Blender File, but invisible in View Layer?

Tags: blend-files, viewlayers

I've run into a situation I've never seen before: I deleted the **Screws Kitbash Payware** mesh objects from the **View Layer** display, but they are still visible in the **Blender File** display. Why? Is this by design? Or is the file corrupted? Thanks. Blender 3.1.2, Windows 11.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you delete objects from your scene, they still remain in the file. They are simply no longer assigned to a scene.

So the objects listed here were obviously part of your scene at some point.

Normally you can delete this data if you really don't need it anymore.

You can do this either via the main menu (*File -> Cleanup*), or by clicking on *Purge* in the upper right corner.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had purged the orphan data, but that didn't remove these legacy objects. That confused me, until it occurred to me that they weren't purged because they were marked as Assets. (That's how I realized these legacy objects were still in the file--they showed up in my Assets library.)